# What controversial things has Oghma done that might test the faith of a cleric who worships him?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, religions-and-deities

There are probably no gods who are completely good acording to "modern standards".

A few days ago, I read here [this post on the /r/DnDNext subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/syq0xu/corellon_is_a_massive_hypocrite/) talking about how Corellon is kind of a dick, and it gave me the idea to "test" the faith of the cleric one of my players is currently playing. They are a fairly devoted cleric of Oghma (Knowledge Domain).

I've been trying to find some things Oghma did that could be presented to their character to "spice things up" with their god; however, I've been having trouble finding anything specific on Oghma, seems like a fairly neutral god who doesn't really get involved in anything.

So for all the lore experts out here, what controversial things has Oghma done that you'd recommend sharing with this cleric to test their faith?

Comment: Hey there. I think the meat of this question is okay, but you're likely going to draw some close-votes with the last line there. We don't take too kindly to opinion based ideas 'round these parts. But the title should be perfectly within our scope (in my opinion).

Comment: @goodguy5: I don't think the final sentence makes it opinion-based. Seems pretty clear they want information on times Oghma: 1) Betrayed his own stated ideals and/or 2) Committed some outright evil act. Evil might be at least partially subjective in the real world, but in D&D lore in many editions it's essentially objectively definable, as are the portfolios and ethos of the various deities, so opinion needn't enter into it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger great. And I see that someone retracted their close vote(s) from when I originally commented. If no one else minds, then neither do I. It read to me as something I'd seen other people cast votes to close for and I didn't want to see that happen. Carry on, all.

Comment: I think the question is mostly answerable, but some of the phrasing should be tightened up to avoid inviting open-ended idea-generation. I've made an edit to try and clarify this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Oghma is canonically fairly non-controversial.

According to the AD&D 2nd edition *Legends & Lore* p.63, Oghma is intolerant of losing worshippers to another deity, and will enact harsh punishment against clerics whose flock switch to another deity. (Note: he doesn't punish his former followers for leaving, he punishes the follower's cleric, which may seem unfair.)

According to *Faiths & Avatars* p.131, Oghma's only real flaw is that he spends too much time implementing convoluted plots rather than taking direct action.

Per the AD&D 2e *Draconomicon* p.40, despite being god of knowledge, Oghma was repeatedly beaten at chess by the brass dragon Ileuthra.

Comment: That last one makes sense to me. While I am a weak chess player personally, I have been told that memorization and knowledge help mid-level players a fair bit, but high level play focuses more on innovation and creativity.